# left join query does not return left table records if right table does not have records

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to output users and their total number of `wins` and `losses` over requested date interval. When I run the query below within a date range that contains records in `results` table, everything works fine. However if a user does not have any records in `results` table for the requested date interval, then no user returned in the request at all. What I want is to return a user record anyway, even if the user does not have any records in `results` table for the requested date interval.

I believe the `GROUP BY` makes it behave that way, but I'm not sure how to configure the query to work the way I need it to.

```
SELECT
    users.name,
    users.division,
    SUM(results.wins) as wins,
    SUM(results.losses) as losses
FROM users LEFT JOIN results ON users.user_id = results.user_id
    AND results.date  BETWEEN {$startDate} AND {$endDate}
WHERE users.user_id = {$user_id} GROUP BY results.user_id;
```

Comment: did you try grouping by `users.user_id`, as that should be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is returned, just on a row where the id is `NULL`.  You are grouping by the id in second table.

Instead, group by the first table field:

```
SELECT u.name, u.division,
       SUM(r.wins) as wins, SUM(r.losses) as losses
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     results r
     ON u.user_id = r.user_id AND r.date BETWEEN {$startDate} AND {$endDate}
WHERE u.user_id = {$user_id}
GROUP BY u.user_id;
---------^
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Simple solution, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: @dmit . . . This is a very subtle problem.  If you have a problem when using outer joins, the first thing to think of is whether you are using columns that have `NULL` values.